# How can Knowledge Graphs be Integrated with Language Models for Semantic Search?

Tags: reference-request, gpt, language-model, knowledge-base, gpt-4

I am exploring the incorporate knowledge graphs (KGs) with language models.

I understand that KGs can provide structured understanding of entities and their relationships which can be crucial for semantic search tasks such as query understanding, and quesiton-answering.

I am particularly interested in practical implementations and would like to know:

What are the common practices for integrating KGs with language models like gpt-4?

I appreciate any insights or references that can guide me in implementing a KG-enhanced gpt-4.